# How can I embed small images into my app?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa, ios5

I have 4 small "LED" icons which I use in my app to indicate the status of the objects in a UITableView and in a subsequent detail view. I don't really want to have to store them online - is there some way to save them as a part of the app? If so, how do I then reference them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just **drag-and-drop** them in your Xcode project.

Then, to "reference" them, you could just use :

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"yourImage" ofType:@"png"];
```

---

**To get the actual `NSImage`** (from your app bundle) :

```
NSString* imagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"yourImage" ofType:@"png"];
NSImage* image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: imagePath];
```

Comment: Thank you. Does this save the actual image, or just the path to the image?

Comment: @HillInHarwich The code I sent you, gets the "path" of the image. If you want to get the actual `NSImage`, look at my updated answer.

Comment: OK - so I guess there is no way of storing the actual image as a resource... :-S Thank you...

Comment: @HillInHarwich What do you mean? If you drag'n'drop the image into your project, the image **will** be copied into your app bundle (so, it'll be in the resources). If you want to use it, you may just drop it via Interface Builder, or do it programmatically with the code I suggested.

Comment: Ok... apologies - I misunderstood! Thank you!

Comment: UITableView so surely UIImage?

Comment: @MattMelton I'm a Cocoa developer (exclusively for Mac) and I tend to be missing that... Good point! :-)

Comment: The easier way to get the image is UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage"];

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage"];
```

Comment: Given the lack of context afforded by the question, this answer requires more substance (IMO)